# Add css to class with style (url) find

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Im looping through all divs on a specific page and look for a url thats defined by a theme in 'style' attribute. If I find the url I would like to add css to a specific class. I am getting no errors, can someone take a look where I took a wrong turn?

Code:

```
if (top.location.pathname === '/news/') {
    $j("div").each(function() {
        if ($j(this).css('background-image') === 'http://daddykate-acc.daddykate.be/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/vc_gitem_image.png') {
            $j('.vc_gitem-zone').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}
```

Little PS: The `$j` is required to make the code work (WP theme obligation)

EDIT: Ok, so I just used the 'setTimeout' function to make the function run after DOM was loaded. Everything is working fine now, Thank you for all the input !

Comment: `$j(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://daddykate-acc.daddykate.be/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/vc_gitem_image.png)' ` ....................................................... check value of `top.location.pathname` and `$j(this).css('background-image')`

Comment: If you use `console.log($j(this).css('background-image'))`, what do you get? Seems obvious to debug, right?!

Comment: The console.log returns none for some weird reason, maybe because dom has not loaded yet? @A.Wolff

Comment: It is being generated by the WP plugin when you don't add an image to your post. I'll investigate. @A.Wolff

Comment: So you have to run your snippet once the plugin has updated the DOM, not before. How to? It depends which plugin you are talking about

Comment: Yea I am researching how to do it, FYI it's Visual Composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking for `background-image` will return somthing like `url("http://...")`, so your check fails here. I would do something with `regex` or `indexOf`:

```
if( top.location.pathname === '/news/' ) {
    $j("div").each(function() {
        if( $j(this).css('background-image').indexOf('daddykate-acc.daddykate.be/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/vc_gitem_image.png') >= 0 ) {
            $j('.vc_gitem-zone').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}
```

And just a hint, you know that you can wrap your code and use `$` instead of `$j`? This would help you to reuse code on other pages.

You can do it with a `ready state` of jQuery:

```
$j(function($) {
    $("div").each(function() { /* ... */ });
});
```

Or with a IIFE:

```
(function($) {
    $("div").each(function() { /* ... */ });
})($j)
```